# Angular dataSource not loading in HTML template

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to load data from an Excel file into an angular application.  I can load the Excel data, parse it to get only the columns I need and store this in an array.  This is done in my service.ts file.

The service is called from the component.ts file as a return.  I verify here that I am getting my data using a console.log().

I am using @Output() to send the data to the child component to display the data as a MatTableDataSource.

I know the html template works as I have put the data into a json-server and called it from there using a service to return the data.

I have tried several different mods to see why the datasource is not being displayed in the html.  My html screen does show that I have a number of records, but no data rows show up.

service.ts

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
import { BoMItem } from '../_models/bomItem';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

const BOM_DATA: BoMItem[] = [];

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ExcelService {

  fileUploaded: File;
  storeData: any;
  worksheet: any;
  jsonData: any;

  myData = {} as BoMItem;

  constructor() { }

  readExcel(filesUploaded: FileList): Observable<any> {
    // console.log(filesUploaded);
    for (const file in filesUploaded) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(filesUploaded, file)) {
        let importFile: File = filesUploaded[file];
        // console.log('File: ', importFile);
        let readFile = new FileReader();
        readFile.onload = (e) => {
          this.storeData = readFile.result;
          let data = new Uint8Array(this.storeData);
          let arr = new Array();
          for (let i = 0; i !== data.length; ++i) {
            arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
          }
          let bstr = arr.join('');
          let workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });
          let firstSheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
          this.worksheet = workbook.Sheets[firstSheetName];
          this.createJsonData();
        };
        readFile.readAsArrayBuffer(importFile);
      }
    }
    return of(BOM_DATA);
  }

  createJsonData() {
    // : Observable<BoMItem[]>
    this.jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(this.worksheet, { raw: false });

    this.jsonData.forEach(element => {
      this.myData = {} as BoMItem;
      for (const key in element) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(element, key)) {
          const item = element[key];
          if (key === 'DESC' || key === 'Description' || key === 'Disc') {
            this.myData.desc = item;
          }
          if (key === 'PART NUMBER' || key === 'MFG PART NUMBER' || key === 'Catalog') {
            this.myData.partNumber = item;
          }
          if (key === 'MFG' || key === 'Manufacturer' || key === 'mfg') {
            this.myData.mfg = item;
          }
          if (key === 'QTY' || key === 'qty' || key === 'Quantity') {
            this.myData.qty = item;
          }
        }
      }
      BOM_DATA.push(this.myData);
    });
    // console.log('BOM_DATA: ', BOM_DATA);
    return of(BOM_DATA);
  }
```

model.ts

```
export interface BoMItem {
    desc: string;
    partNumber: string;
    mfg: string;
    qty: string;
    supplierName?: string;
  }
```

parent component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { ExcelService } from 'src/app/_services/excel.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bom-load',
  templateUrl: './bom-load.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bom-load.component.css']
})
export class BomLoadComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output()
  data: any;

  constructor(
    private excelService: ExcelService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  uploadedFile(evt) {
    return this.excelService.readExcel(evt.target.files).subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.data = response;
      console.log('bom-load: ', this.data);
    });
  }
}
```

child component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { BoMItem } from 'src/app/_models/bomItem';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BomService } from 'src/app/_services/bom.service';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-bom-list',
  templateUrl: './bom-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bom-list.component.css']
})
export class BomListComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('bomForm', { static: false})
  bomForm: NgForm;

  bomData: BoMItem;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['desc', 'partNumber', 'mfg', 'qty', 'supName', 'actions'];
  // displayedColumns: string[] = ['desc', 'partNumber', 'mfg', 'qty', 'actions'];

  @Input()
  data: any[];

  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<BoMItem>;

  isEditMode = false;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private bomService: BomService) {
    this.bomData = {} as BoMItem;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
    // this.getAllBomItems();
    console.log('bom-list: ', this.dataSource);
    // this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    // this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  getAllBomItems() {
    this.bomService.getList().subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.dataSource.data = response;
    });
  }

  editItem(element) {
    this.bomData = _.cloneDeep(element);
    this.isEditMode = true;
  }

  cancelEdit() {
    this.isEditMode = false;
    this.bomForm.resetForm();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.bomForm.form.valid) {
      if (this.isEditMode) {
        this.updateBomItem();
      }
      else {
        this.addBomItem();
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Enter valid data!');
    }
  }

  addBomItem() {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }

  updateBomItem() {
    this.bomService.updateItem(this.bomData.partNumber, this.bomData).subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.map((o: BoMItem) => {
        if (o.partNumber === response.partNumber) {
          o = response;
        }
        return o;
      });
      this.getAllBomItems();
    });
  }

}
```

parent component.html

```
<mat-toolbar>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" (change)="uploadedFile($event)" placeholder="Upload file"
        accept=".xls,.xlsx" multiple>
</mat-toolbar>

<div *ngIf="data != null">
    <app-bom-list [data]="data"></app-bom-list>
</div>
```

child component.html

```
<div class="container">
   
        <ng-container *ngIf="isEditMode;">
            <button mat-button color="warn">Update</button>
            <a mat-button color="warn" (click)="cancelEdit()">Cancel</a>
        </ng-container>
    </form> -->

    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="desc">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Description</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.desc }}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="partNumber">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Part Number</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.partNumber}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="mfg">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Manufacturer</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.mfg}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="qty">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Quantity </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.qty}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="supName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Supplier Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.supplierName}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                <!-- <button mat-icon-button color="primary">
                    <mat-icon aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon">add</mat-icon>
                </button> -->
            </mat-header-cell>

            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i=index;">
                <button mat-icon-button color="accent">
                    <mat-icon aria-label="Edit" (click)="editItem(element)">edit</mat-icon>
                </button>

                <button mat-icon-button color="accent">
                    <mat-icon aria-label="Delete">delete</mat-icon>
                </button>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

    </table>

    <mat-paginator [length]="dataSource?.data.length" [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100, 500]">
    </mat-paginator>

</div>
```

Console.Log information:

```
bom-load:  
[]
0: {qty: "6", mfg: "Mencom", partNumber: "1321-3R8-C", desc: "480V 3-PHASE AC DRIVE REACTORS, OPEN TYPE, 8A, 3 HP Drive"}
1: {qty: "1", mfg: "AB", partNumber: "1756-EN2T", desc: "1756 CONTROL LOGIX ETHERNET / IP BRIDGE MODULE (128 TCP/IP CONNECTIONS)"}
2: {qty: "1", mfg: "AB", partNumber: "1756-EN2TR", desc: "1756 CONTROL LOGIX ETHERNET / IP BRIDGE MODULE (128 TCP/IP CONNECTIONS) REDUNDANT"}
3: {qty: "1", mfg: "AB", partNumber: "1756-L81E", desc: "1756 CONTROL LOGIX CONTROLLER, USER MEMORY 3MB, 1Gb ENET PORT"}
4: {qty: "6", mfg: "AB", partNumber: "25B-D6P0N104", desc: "POWERFLEX 525 VARIABLE FREQUENCY DRIVE 3 HP, 480VAC 3 PH, FRAME A"}
5: {qty: "6", mfg: "AB", partNumber: "25-COMM-E2P", desc: "POWERFLEX 525 DUAL-PORT ETHERNET/IP MODULE"}
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
bom-list.component.ts:43 bom-list:  
MatTableDataSource {_renderData: BehaviorSubject, _filter: BehaviorSubject, _internalPageChanges: Subject, _renderChangesSubscription: Subscriber, sortingDataAccessor: ƒ, …}
filterPredicate: (data, filter) => {…}
filteredData: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
sortData: (data, sort) => {…}
sortingDataAccessor: (data, sortHeaderId) => {…}
_data: BehaviorSubject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(1), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
_filter: BehaviorSubject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(1), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
_internalPageChanges: Subject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
_renderChangesSubscription: Subscriber {closed: false, _parentOrParents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, syncErrorThrown: false, …}
_renderData: BehaviorSubject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(1), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
data: Array(6)
0: {qty: "6", mfg: "Mencom", partNumber: "1321-3R8-C", desc: "480V 3-PHASE AC DRIVE REACTORS, OPEN TYPE, 8A, 3 HP Drive"}
1: {qty: "1", mfg: "AB", partNumber: "1756-EN2T", desc: "1756 CONTROL LOGIX ETHERNET / IP BRIDGE MODULE (128 TCP/IP CONNECTIONS)"}
2: {qty: "1", mfg: "AB", partNumber: "1756-EN2TR", desc: "1756 CONTROL LOGIX ETHERNET / IP BRIDGE MODULE (128 TCP/IP CONNECTIONS) REDUNDANT"}
3: {qty: "1", mfg: "AB", partNumber: "1756-L81E", desc: "1756 CONTROL LOGIX CONTROLLER, USER MEMORY 3MB, 1Gb ENET PORT"}
4: {qty: "6", mfg: "AB", partNumber: "25B-D6P0N104", desc: "POWERFLEX 525 VARIABLE FREQUENCY DRIVE 3 HP, 480VAC 3 PH, FRAME A"}
5: {qty: "6", mfg: "AB", partNumber: "25-COMM-E2P", desc: "POWERFLEX 525 DUAL-PORT ETHERNET/IP MODULE"}
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
filter: (...)
paginator: (...)
sort: (...)
__proto__: DataSource
```

Image of html table trying to use data loaded from Excel
[image: Screen image of table showing pagination count but no rows]

Image of static data using this.getAllBomItems
[image: Image of static data using this.getAllBomItems()]

Interesting development:

by adding; as suggested; ngOnChanges(), I now get data, but ONLY after clicking the pagination buttons.

```
  ngOnChanges() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    console.log('bom-list: ', this.dataSource);
    console.log('this.data: ', this.data);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
```

Comment: It will probably not solve your issue, but you don't need ```@Output()``` on data in your parent component. Outputs have a specific semantic where you use them on properties that are going to serve as EventEmitters and can be bound to by parent components, which is not how you are using ```data: any```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Instead of using `ngOnInit`, try to use `ngOnChanges` in your child component.

And try to use `ChangeDetectorRef`.

```js
constructor (
  ...
  private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
) {}

ngOnChanges() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

**Note**

```html
<div *ngIf="data != null">
```

Change the above line into:

```html
<div *ngIf="data">
```

You data value is `undefined` so `*ngIf="data != null"` this expression will be truthy. So the `ngOnInit` of your child component will be called without the `data`.

Also you need to update the below code too:

```js
getAllBomItems() {
    this.bomService.getList().subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response);
      // this.dataSource.data = response; <- your table will not detect change with this line, you must replace the whole dataSource object.
    });
  }
```

Comment: The getAllBomItems() is the method that pulls from the static json data file I used for testing.  In the test, it was called from the ngOnInit() <should be commented out>.

Comment: Yes.  No change.

Comment: can you attach your screenshot of your table?

Comment: image added to question.

Comment: it can be related to your css styles?

Comment: Added image showing static data.  Only change was to uncomment in ngOnInit() the getAllBomItems().

Comment: hmm weird, finally, can you try add `console.log(this.data)` in the `ngOnInit` of child component?

Comment: also Instead of using ngOnInit, try to use ngOnChange in your child component.

Comment: this.data returns the expected data.  Same as the bom-load and the MatTableDAtaSource.data<Array> as noted originally.

Comment: please try to replace your `ngOnInit` with `ngOnChange`. so put the `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(response);` inside `ngOnChange`

Comment: Interesting development.  Adding ngOnChanges, when I click on the paginator buttons, my data shows up; but not until I click to move forward or back through the data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219367/discussion-between-lsieting-and-yash).

Answer (score 0):

try inject `ChangeDetectorRef` in your component with contains your datatable and call like this:

```js
  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

//after add new data to your table
this.cdRef.detectChanges();
```